# Secure Server start up

Tags: server

From the server implementations that I have seen, people normally use a properties file with all the passwords (that may be encrypted with hardcoded key(s)).

I have therefore, created a server that takes localhost inputs.

However, that is vulnerable to sniffers on the host machine.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Depends on the threat model. Defending against root on the host machine, tho, is a research project.

Comment: I think your question needs more context. What kind of servers you are taking about, what should the server do with *"all the passwords"* etc. It might be that you are talking about a TLS server which needs a password to load the private key of the certificate - but this is just one of several possible interpretations of your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich all the passwords, meaning all. tls, db. all. ALL. everything. the answer sought is not "what keys", but how to send secrets to a server more securely than exposing a file (that must be written on the hdd), or through network connections, that can be sniffed on server start up. i do not believe "what keys" has anything to do with "my interpretation of my question".